# setLocale seems to be delayed

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to setLocale on a JSP page, but it feels like it's delayed or something I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why...

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<c:set var="language" value="${not empty param.lang ? param.lang : not empty language ? language : 'en_HK'}" scope="session" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="i18n.common" scope="session"/>
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}" scope="session"/>
${language}
<fmt:message key="nav.home" />
```

The first time I load http://localhost:8080/, I'll get

```
en_HK 主页
```

I refresh the page:

```
en_HK Home
```

Then I load http://localhost:8080/?lang=zh_HK

```
zh_HK Home
```

Then I load http://localhost:8080/

```
zh_HK 主頁
```

Then http://localhost:8080/?lang=zh_CN

```
zh_CN 主頁
```

I refresh page

```
zh_CN 主页
```

.... I seem to only get the locale set for the next time I load the page....

Please help me spot what's wrong...

More info:
If I don't set the setLocale scope to session/application, it never changes.

Answer (score 0):

That was embarrassing, for those who may have made the same mistake here was the problem:

setLocale should have been called *before* setBundle, i.e.

```
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="text"/>
```